# Should the reflection coefficient be negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, reflection

According to Fresnel's equations for the magnetic field parallel to the surface of a dielectric, the reflection coefficient is this:
$$r_{s}=\frac{\cos\theta^{i}-\frac{n_2}{n_1}\cos\theta^{t}}{\cos\theta^{i}+\frac{n_2}{n_1}\cos\theta^{t}}\tag{R}$$

In all the examples I have found, the magnetic field's direction "looks"(I'm not sure what is the correct term) at the reader (like this)[image]
However, when the magnetic field "looks down", like this[image]

the reflection coefficient I have found is the negative of Fresnel's.
$$r_{s}=\frac{-\cos\theta^{i}+\frac{n_2}{n_1}\cos\theta^{t}}{\cos\theta^{i}+\frac{n_2}{n_1}\cos\theta^{t}}\tag{R}$$ Is this correct or are my calculations wrong? [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353917/why-does-a-negative-reflection-coefficient-correspond-to-a-phase-difference-of) the user concludes that this is caused by a phase shift, is that the case here too?

Comment: -1 Not useful. You seem to be asking us to check your calculation, or to confirm something which is already stated and explained in another question.

Comment: I am asking whther or not that result makes sense for the given data, or if soeone has seen similar results for them

Comment: or, can fresnel's equations change based on the magnetic fields's direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you've changed the direction of the incoming magnetic field $\vec{H}_{\pi 0}$ but kept $\hat{u}_\pi$ pointing in the same direction, then you must have implicitly changed the direction of the incoming electric field $\vec{E}_{\pi0}$ (since $\vec{E} \times \vec{H} \propto \vec{k}$.)   Since the Fresnel coefficient is defined as the ratio of $\vec{E}_{\alpha0}$ to $\vec{E}_{\pi0}$, it makes sense that flipping the sign of the magnetic (and electric) field flips the sign of the Fresnel coefficient;  it's merely a matter of the definitions you choose.